# Install SSL Certificate on Azure Cloud Service (VM)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, azure

I have an SSL certificate for domain example.com and I want to access my Azure Cloud Service exampleserver.cloudapp.net as https://server.example.com. I am using Virtual Machine to access this Cloud Service, **not Web & Worker Roles**.

I have created an A entry pointing server.example.com to exampleserver.cloudapp.net.

I have successfully uploaded the SSL certificate on the Cloud Service -> Certificates tab, and I have added the endpoint on the Linux VM associated with the Cloud Service, from private port 443 to public port 443. I didn't enter any ACL.

Now I am trying to configure the SSL following [this tutorial](https://support2.microsoft.com/common/survey.aspx?scid=sw;en;3864&showpage=1) but I don't have any configuration or definition files in my app, and I don't have how to upload them (the Cloud Service -> Configuration tab on portal.azure.com does not exist anymore).

What can I do to have this working?

Comment: Are you using virtual machines or web/worker roles of cloud services? Although Virtual Machines use cloud services they are not the same thing.

Comment: I am using virtual machines

Answer (score 4):

The tutorial you are following is for web/worker roles cloud services and not Virtual Machines. Although a VM uses the cloud service layer, it's not the same thing. All you have to do is to install the certificate as you would in any windows server machine and add the Host A register to your DNS provider.

[SSL Certificates CSR Creation :: IIS 8 and IIS 8.5](https://www.digicert.com/csr-creation-microsoft-iis-8.htm)

[IIS 8 and IIS 8.5 SSL Certificate Installation](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-microsoft-iis-8.htm)

**Update**: In case of Apache (Linux)

[OpenSSL CSR Creation for Apache SSL](https://www.digicert.com/csr-creation-apache.htm)

[Apache SSL Certificate Installation](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-apache.htm)

Also, make sure to reserve your public in order to keep it in a event of shutdown or restart of your virtual machines.

[Reserved IP Overview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that the VM is Linux. Does it make any difference? I successfully uploaded the SSL certificates through portal.azure.com on the Cloud Service -> Certificates tab. However, https://server.example.com doesn't work.

Comment: forget certificates tab. It won't affect anything. The certificate MUST be installed in your virtual machine. You are not using roles Cloud Service (the one you deploy with visual studio and it's managed by Microsoft - PaaS model), you are running regular Virtual Machine (IaaS model).